# Delete a specific node in a Linked list using STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

```
 struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
class linklist
{
    node* head;
public:
    linklist(){ head = NULL;}

  void Delete_a_Node( ? , ? ); \\ Not getting how to call this function
 };

int main()
{
    list<int> l1;
    linklist ll1;
          .
          .
          .

    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++)
    {
        cin >> element;
        l1.push_back(element);
    }
    cout << "Original list: " << endl;

    list<int>::iterator p = l1.begin(); // Printing List elements.
    while (p != l1.end()){
        cout << *p << " ";
        p++;
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "which node do you want to delete" << endl;
    cin >> m;
    ll1.Delete_a_Node(m, p); \\ Getting Error
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Here ,I have created a list using **list class**. Now  I want to delete specific node ( 2nd, or 3rd, or anything ) without using list class member functions. But not getting how to call Delete_a_Node() function.
  How to pass Head ( in which address of starting node is stored ) node ?? 
I want to learn STL, so used class list and iterator purposely.

Comment: It seems you want `void Delete_a_Node(int offset, std::list<int>& l) { l.erase(std::next(l.begin(), offset)); }`

Comment: Why do you use `std::list` and `linklist` at the same time? Function `Delete_a_Node` have no definition in the code you posted. There are `?` which is not valid C++. You should precise all the errors you get. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ Drop : Delete_a_node() is not a member function of class list , it is a user made function. So to access that function I used linklist.

Comment: @ Jarod42 : Sorry but I did not get your code fully. Now consider , Delete_a_node () function should not used class <list> member function. In short I want to ask you , how to do program, which is half made by STL and half made by normal object oriented programming. ( Here , creating linked list is done by STL , but deleting a node should not be done by STL.

Comment: `ll1` was never populated; no nodes were added to it, so there are no nodes to delete from it. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ Igor Tandetnik : ll1 is just one of my try to call Delete_a_node() function , which is giving me error. So I am not getting how to call Delete_a_node() function.

Comment: If you are hoping to somehow peek inside the internal implementation details of `std::list` and manipulate its data structures, then a) you won't be able to, in any sane and reasonable manner, and b) why on earth would you want to, in the first place? What's the real goal you are trying to achieve? As stated, the question looks suspiciously like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)